# add click event to string elements in array passed to div

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, events, click

I have a map based application, where I need to click on the map to retrieve the names of any features at that point, then be able to see that list of feature names in a popup, and click each name. Ill then use the name retrieved from that click, to select that feature in the map.

I am getting stuck trying to add a click event to each individual name in the array I used to populate the div in the popup. I am trying to populate an array with the list of names, then push that array into a div, which is rendered in the popup. It seems like when I append the div with the text, I end up with one string that I can't iterate through, and I can't seem to add an event to the name before I push into an array.

In the case below, addEventListener results in an error (...is not a function) .. I assume b/c I have not yet added anything to the DOM:

```
    var thisname = feature.get('mapfeature_name');
    thisname.addEventListener('click', function(){
        ...
    });
    // error : addEventListener is not a function
```

I've tried some variation like this below, which renders links but I only get back the entire list, not the individual name:

```
namelist.push("<a href = '#'>" + thisname + "</a>");

$('#namehtml').html(eventlist.join(', '));
$('#namehtml').click (function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
    // prints entire array of names, not just the one I clicked on
});
```

I can't access the div as any sort of list, so far.

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Strings don't have event handlers.  They don't get events.  DOM Elements do.  You would need to put the event handler on the `<a>` tag you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

answer based on Taplar's comment above:
first add class to a tag:

```
namelist.push("<a href = '#' class='this_name' >" + thisname + "</a>");
```

then add click event to that class:

```
    $('.this_name').click(function(){
       console.log($(this).text());
    });
```